# python - Запланированная рассылка сообщений Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-2.7, laravel-5.6, рассылка

**Дано:** Telegram бот, написанный на python с использованием [pyTelegramBotApi](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). Все пользователи бота хранятся в таблице `users`. СУБД - MySQL.
Админ. панель - на Laravel. В админке есть функционал рассылки сообщений: редактор заполняет форму с полями "Заголовок", "Сообщение", "Картинка" и "Дата отправки", после отправки которой данные записываются в таблицу `broadcast`.

**Вопрос:** Как запустить рассылку по выбранной дате? Написать функцию, которая будет каждые n-секунд отправлять запрос в базу и проверять вот так:

```
if(now == broadcast_send_date):
    bot.send_message(...)
```

Или есть методы попроще/получше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверять на "<" ("меньше") дату отправки. Забирать из базы сообщения, дата отправки которых меньше, чем `time.time()`. Если сообщение одноразовое, ставить некий флаг типа `sended = True`, для регулярных (повторяемых) метку `sended` не ставить, а просто при отправке прибавлять интервал отправки к дате отправки.

Comment: О, спасибо, примерно так и хотел, но что-то подсказывало что решение не ахти и есть другие, о которых я, будучи новичком в python, еще не знаю :D

Comment: @DauletMyrzan я просто сам писал похожую тему по работе, применил именно этот подход. Хз костыль или нет, но полёт нормальный уже почти год, с прошлого августа